# Is there any practical algorithm / data-structure that can't be done with non-recursive Lambda Calculus augmented with foldl?

Tags: programming-languages, functional-programming, data-structures, lambda

In my search for a practical non-turing complete programming language, I've been paying attention to lambda-calculus with disallowed self-application - that is, `x x` forbidden. After taking that language and augmenting it with lists and the `foldl` and `range` operations, pretty much any algorithm I've tried so far is implementable. It is trivial to implement `filter`, `reverse`, `head`, `tail`, `map`, `scanl`, `zip` and many others - foldl replaces the need for recursion.

Can you think in any practical, important algorithm that would be undoable in that language?

> It is no coincidence that all of them use self-application—the
>   application of an expression to itself. It is through
>   self-application that repetitive computation can be simulated in the
>   lambda calculus. Indeed, the third of the previous three examples is
>   famous because it can encode recursive function deﬁnitions.

From http://people.cis.ksu.edu/~schmidt/705s13/Lectures/ch6.pdf .

Comment: Undoable, or unfeasible due to excessive slowdown?

Comment: Undoable / completely impossible. But if you think something would be completely slow please warn me, I've actually got great results in execution speed (with fusion and optimizations possible from lack of side-effects). For example, `len` (or `(lambda(foldl(lambda(a)(lambda(b)(succ a))) 0 a))`) is simply compiled to `O(1)`, regardless of needing one `foldl`.

Comment: Have you tried anything hat usually requires binary trees and/or random access to implement efficiently, such as associative maps? It appears to me that virtually all operations in this category would become linear time instead of logarithmic or constant time. This in turn makes many algorithms quadratic time instead of n log n time. Edit: I'm assuming "list" means linked list, so how can length be O(1) without compiler magic introducing a special cased `length` field?

Comment: Hm in that case I'm actually using arrays on the compiled version. Can you think something else? Trees are actually one thing I'm not sure will be possible to implement with foldl alone/no recursion.

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure you can replace every interesting tree with a flat list of some kind, at the cost of exponential slowdown. This is one of the reasons for more sophisticated means of guaranteeing termination (such as structural recursion) AFAIK.

Comment: @delnan would you tell me more about?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12163/discussion-between-delnan-and-dokkat)

Comment: Care to explain how you're implementing foldl without recursion? I suspect there's something I'm unawares of that is commonly known in this regard, but my immediate knowledge of pure lists is that recursion is required for iteration

Comment: @JimmyHoffa He's embedded it as a primitive. But I'm unclear on what exactly `range` does. Lambda calculus doesn't have any numbers so what's the ordering implied by range?

Comment: Also, if this language isn't turing complete, by definition there is some interesting algorithm that can't be implemented. The interesting question really is whether you can jam a fixed point in there. If you include an operation similar to `cons` than I don't see why not.

Comment: And how do you verify that there isn't self application? `f [f]` should be legal. Taking an [iso-recursive Y combinator](http://jozefg.bitbucket.org/posts/2013-11-09-iso-recursive-types.html) and changing `fold'` and `unfold'` to `\x -> cons x ()' and `car` respectively should work.

Comment: I'm actually including numbers and algebraic operations as primitives, along with foldl and range, that generates a list such as `(range 1 5) -> (list 1 2 3 4)` because I couldn't figure out how to do this with the other primitives alone. With that initial set I've managed to implement everything I've tried so far, thus the question. I thought I included that information on the question, but I didn't. I'm sorry. The complete list of primitives is: `lambda if var num arr nil foldl range add mul div not or and sub eq ltn`, chosen for being machine-friendly.

Comment: @Dokkat that sounds turing complete to me, I'm not sure why you think it's not? foldl (or just list iteration in general which foldl can be defined in terms of) + function application is probably all you need to be turing complete. I have used non-recursive foldl organizations to cause indirect recursion so I know it can be done.

Comment: @jozefg pardon, I don't understand how that'd work. I've read in an article that lambda calculus without self-application isn't turing complete. I could be wrong, obviously, I've not put too much thought on that particularly. But I'd like to see a concrete example.

Comment: @Dokkat Ok, original question, Can we get an example of range?

Comment: @jozefg pardon, original question what? I provided an example of range above, `(range 1 4)` -> `(list (num 1) (num 2) (num 3))`. I guess this is necessary because there is no other way to generate populated lists without having one initially, and there is no way to generate a bigger list than what you already have. So you can't create a list of N elements from just the native numbers and foldl. I guess `range` makes the connection between numbers and lists.

Comment: Oh sorry I missed that. My thought is to take a look at church numerals, you can eliminate almost all of those primitives. You can build all of this stuff in vanilla lambda calculus without any primitives remember.

Comment: @Dokkat lambda calculus without self-application can't define any form of list iteration, as soon as you make list iteration (such as foldl) a primitive, your making a turing complete language.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa I'm not entirely sure, since church lists don't need self application AFAIK and they give rise to `foldr`.

Comment: @jozefg (Woops! Church numbers actually don't need self-application.) I understand what you are saying but I'd need a concrete example. How could you cause a non-termination with those alone?

Comment: @Dokkat I'm voting to close as too broad, you clearly aren't sure what you're asking here and this has devolved completely into a discussion which is apparently what you want. I think this question should be locked until you can reform it into something based on a more comprehensively provable fact (like the idea that the language you defined isn't turing complete - which I'm quite certain that it is; causing the whole question to not really be valid)

Comment: @JimmyHoffa I agree with closure under the terms that the question is invalid for the language being turing complete, but I believe it is valid from the source I've read, while you're basing your assumption that it is invalid merely on your opinion and memories of an unrelated case. It is nonsensical to vote for closure for that reason when you are not sure it is non-turing complete yourself, nor can present a concrete example of so.

Comment: @Dokkat Can you cite this article please?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find a paper with a proper proof, one probably doesn't even exist. But I can cite some sources of authority that will give some confidence for a while. [This answer here](http://goo.gl/Q152oi) affirms that on the second paragraph. [This](http://goo.gl/u8TIvD) material from a colorado university CS course says so on the 22th slide for the Y-combinator. Some [other sources](http://goo.gl/HSM1wB) affirm it is how we get recursion "generally", and nowhere I could find a way around that. I guess that is enough to assume that it is at least plausible, if not probable.

Comment: @Dokkat Yeah I think you're in trouble here, read that blog post I linked above. It has an application of the Y combinator without self application. It relies on type level recursion but you don't have types so that's a non-issue. Voting to close.

Comment: It relies on unfold. It could be the case that unfold is not implementable on this language. We do not know.

Comment: @Dokkat `fold` and `unfold` are synonymous with `cons x Unit` and `car`. Which can be written with church pairs. Without self application. You need a type system to formalize the fact that what you want is "no infinite types". This can guarantee nontermination.

Comment: @jozefg it depends on `unfold` which is not possible on this language as you can't generate lists other than using `range`. Your argument is invalid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**tl;dr (or I don't know what a Y combinator is)**

This question is based on the assumption that the above defined language is not Turing-complete, it actually is Turing-complete and therefore the question is invalid - all algorithms can be expressed in the language defined above as is the meaning of Turing-completeness.

---

Ok. Well apparently this has to be explicitly written out.

Proof of turing completeness follows trivially from unbounded recursion which can be derived from a fixpoint combinator.

Note the traditional Y combinator

```
Y f = (\x -> f (x x)) (\x -> f (x x))
```

Define

```
cons = \a b f -> f a b
car  = \x y -> x
cdr  = \x y -> y

fst  = \p -> p car
snd  = \p -> p cdr
```

This is just the standard encoding of church pairs.

```
nil = \x -> x -- Or anything really
fold = \x -> cons x nil
unfold = \x -> fst x
```

Then

```
Y f = (\x -> f (unfold x x)) (fold (\x -> f (unfold x x)))
```

No self application, but this still correctly encodes the Y combinator. I previously [wrote this out](http://jozefg.bitbucket.org/posts/2013-11-09-iso-recursive-types.html) in Haskell. There `fold` and `unfold` require more interesting jiggery-pokery because of types, but since lambda calculus has none we can safely ignore it :)

We've just proven we have a Turing-complete language. Every algorithm is therefore exactly as efficient as can be encoded in a Lambda Calculus. This also invalidates the question's original premise that the language is Turing-incomplete.

Comment: For those of us that are hopelessly dense, can you tell us how this relates to the original question?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Whoops sorry, this shows that Lambda calculus without self application is still turing complete. Therefore it is exactly as expressive lambda calculus.

Comment: Alright, points for you. On the meantime, Tromps suggested this even simpler proof my premise was false: `Y' = (λx. λy. x y x) (λy. λx. y (x y x))`